# Private nameserver IP

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, nameserver

I am working on a VPS.  The server we are using was installed with WHM Accelerated and CPanel, the option we selected for DNS was BIND.

When I came to updating the Nameservers on the Domain Registrar's website I received an error, unhelpfully this was not explained by the system and we were told to call support. After a chat with support they confirmed everything was okay on their side of things. This meant that something was wrong on the server!

The first place I started was with the DNS zone records. Following this, awful helpful Host Gator tutorial:  support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/linux-dedicated-hosting/how-to-initially-configure-your-server-via-whm-part-2. The basic gist of it is I set up ns1 to point to the static IP using an A record. The same for ns2, I then set up two NS records pointing xx.com to ns1.xx.com and ns2.xx.com. I have also updated the SOA record to include ns1.xx.com. Below is a screen shot of what I have for the DNS zone record for xx.com:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD00e.jpg]

This all seemed fine to me. I am not sure why this isn't working at all. This DNS zone is for xx.com and belongs to the account xx. I have messed around with the TTL settings, but I don't think that would have such an impact?

Believing this to be correct I have looked else where on the server. When I check out the "NS Record Report" ns1.xx.com and ns2.xx.com do exist! But neither of them do have a resolved IP address:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/les8Z.jpg]

After some research regarding this I found that the issue could be that the IPs just haven't refreshed in CPanel, fair enough, I updated them with SSH using the following commands:

```
root@server [~]# /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenameserverips
```

And then, checking the file with the IPs in shows:

```
root@server [~]# cat /var/cpanel/nameserverips.yaml
--- 
ns1.heliops.co: 
  count: 1
  zones: heliops.co
ns2.heliops.co: 
  count: 1
  zones: heliops.co
```

If I run the same two commands again, this is the result I am getting:

```
root@server [~]# /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenameserverips
root@server [~]# cat /var/cpanel/nameserverips.yaml
--- 
ns1.heliops.co: 
  "": 0
  count: 1
  zones: heliops.co
ns2.heliops.co: 
  "": 0
  count: 1
  zones: heliops.co
```

As you can see the "": 0 makes an appearance out of nowhere. From looking around the internet, I can see that this is where the IP address should appear. I think?

There doesn't appear to be an associated IP address. I also came across the following command:

```
root@server [~]# cat /etc/nameserverips
```

I thought this would make the actual IPs show up in the terminal, but nope! It returns absolutely nothing. Just takes me to the next input in the terminal.

I thought maybe the issue was that BIND had not started, as I had previously had issues with Apache, but I restarted the system and everything was working fine. So I have gathered that is not the issue.

I found another thing I thought may have helped in Server Management->Basic cPanel & WHM Setup. At the very bottom of the page I found 4 name server settings. Two of them were empty the top 2 have two name server options, belonging to the company we are renting the server from. They both have the current IP assigned to them, they are also the current name servers in on the domain registrar for xx.com. I haven't touched them anymore than clicking the Assign IP button because I didn't want to accidentally break WHM or CPanel.

Comment: We explicitly do not cater for "I have no clue how to be an administrator" users here. "I have very little experience with networking and servers," translates into one advice: find a job you are qualified for and tell your superiors to hire someone to do this job because you are not qualified. Or grab some books and get going. Do not expect free consultation over the air on a site that caters for professionals only.

Comment: I do have limited experience, but I am still a paid professional with 5/6 years experience with DNS. It is my first time working on a dedicated server however and I have become stumped. I have spent alot of time reading up on the issue online, the equivalent to grabbing some books, getting nowhere I thought I should ask a question to more experienced professionals. I am confused as to why "I have no clue how to be an administrator" is in quotes. I did not write that, and I can't find it explicitly written in this sites guidelines? But I do agree with what you say. Maybe I undersold myself

Comment: *"I did not write that, and I can't find it explicitly written in this sites guidelines?"* TomTom was paraphrasing. You can take a gander at our meta question on [what professional capacity means](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) which is linked from the page about what is [on topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for here. Search for "is a professional", and note qualities such as "the right details instead of all of the details" and "skill in the technology under question".

Comment: Why are you using cPanel/WHM at all? This is a very nonstandard (and usually not professional) setup and the level of support we can provide is minimal. Your first stop should be cPanel's own support channels.

Comment: @AndrewB thanks, that makes perfect sense to me having read through those posts. I think I should have looked a bit harder, I am at fault for not realising this was a forum directed at actual sysadmins, for example. I just thought it could have been conveyed in a politer fashion!

Comment: @MichaelHampton hi, what would you suggest as an alternative? I should really have thought about going there in the first place, wasn't sure if the issue was whm/cpanel or a actually a server issue.

Comment: Are you sure you properly setup the [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records)?  BTW, your question would be a lot better if you took the time and cut it down to the essentials.  I really don't care that you re-built Apache, if that has nothing to do with the problem you are asking about.  Your question has far too much irrelevant detail.